# Postgres update where id in (list) not updating the last entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, push-notification

I am building a ruby on rails backend to support an ios and android application.  A piece of the code was supposed to handle chat message being pushed via push notification.  For some reason when these query ran

```
[2014-03-05 09:36:38.242] [DEBUG] ^[[1m^[[35mRpush::Notification Load (2.5ms)^[[0m  SELECT "rpush_notifications".* FROM "rpush_notifications" WHERE (delivered = 'f' AND failed = 'f' AND (deliver_after IS NULL OR deliver_after < '2014-03-05 14:36:38.238624')) AND (app_id IN (1,2)) (pid:7523)
[2014-03-05 09:36:41.410] [DEBUG] ^[[1m^[[36mSQL (41.7ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mUPDATE "rpush_notifications" SET delivered = 't', delivered_at = '2014-03-05 14:36:41.258814' WHERE "rpush_notifications"."id" IN (187, 188)^[[0m (pid:7523)
```

The result in my tables looks like

```
id  | delivered |        delivered_at        | failed |         failed_at          
-----+-----------+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------
 188 | f         |                            | f      | 
 187 | t         | 2014-03-05 14:36:41.258814 | f      | 
 186 | t         | 2014-03-05 14:33:55.845077 | f      |
```

Notice how the first row with id 188 did not get updated and id 187 did, and the timestamp there matches the query.  Anyone know why this is happening?

**EDIT:**
Found out there was a row locking condition in the code and fixed it there

Comment: What about the other WHERE conditions? The id is just one of them...

Comment: no that's it, the id is the only one they need.  And after further test, it always seems somehow the second statement was able to execute before the insert of 188 is completed... is it possible somehow when they called the 2nd statement, 188 is not saved yet? but somehow is known by the first statement and called by the second

Answer (score 0):

Found out there was a row locking condition in the code and fixed the problem when it was removed.